# Could someone explain how this python code works?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I’ve been thinking about a piece of code I can’t understand for the last few days.
I fear it’s something really simple, but still.. I have to know how it works, it just bothers me. Thanks in advance.

```
a = [1,1,2,3,5,8]
for a[1] in a:
 pass
print(a)
```

the output of this code is:

```
[1,8,2,3,5,8]
```

How does that happen?

Comment: At every iteration of the loop you are assigning the value to index 1 of a i.e a[1].since last value that will be assigned is 8 , a[1] is 8 in final output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop is effectively equivalent to:

```
for x in a:
    a[1] = x
```

So each time through the loop, it sets `a[1]` to the current element of the list. At the end, it contains the last element of the list.

Comment: So, it's iterating through all the items and replaces a[1] with the last one? (8 in this case)

Comment: The first iteration replaces it with the first element. The second iteration replaces it with the 2nd element. And so on until the last iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating `a[1]` iteratively.
Since the last value is 8, `a[1]` becomes 8 after all.

Answer (score -1):

As Kota Mori said, you are updating it recursively, but that can be sort of hard to find the intuition for, it helps alot to also print the value too. Take a look at this modified code :

```
a = [1,1,2,3,5,8]
for a[2] in a:
    print(a[2])
    pass
print(a)
```

That will print

```
1
1
1
3
5
8
[1, 1, 8, 3, 5, 8]
```

So you can see that even at the start, it has the value of 1 not 2. Thats because thats the first value you get when you iterate. Essentially it set a[2] = a[0].

By the time it finishes looping, a[2] is set to the last value "8" and that is why it gives you the result it does.